# Persisting values in windows workflow foundation 4.0

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I've a windows workflow service that is hosted in a console application. I have a count variable in the service and the value is incremented in each call, how I can make the count value to be persistent between calls.

EDITED: The workflow takes a timeout value as input and returns an id. If you pass 10 as the timeout value the workflow delays for 10 seconds and return the id 1. In between if another client pass 3 as the timeout value a new instance of workflow has to be created and it has to wait for 3 seconds returning the new id value as 2.

Comment: Is this count shared across workflows or per-workflow?

Comment: @Richard I added little more information to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to a variable per workflow instance you can create a variable at the root sequence of you workflow and store. If the workflow is persisted to disk this variable will be saved with it.

However from you question it seems you are referring to a variable per workflow type. In that case there is no static variable per workflow type and you need to manage the state outside of the workflow and persist it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using WorkflowService having the CanCreateInstance of receive activity as true and I'm storing the count variable at the root sequence activity. For every service call  the count variable is always intialized as 0. I'm looking for a way it has to be updated as 1,2,3 in every call.

Comment: So you are creating a new workflow instance every time and you should be using the second option and saving the state outside of the workflow.

Comment: Yes, do I need to save the state outside to achieve this? Is it possible to make the workflowservice as singleton?

Comment: Yes you can but in that case you need to set message correlation for each request to go to the same workflow and structure your in such a way that it doesn't finish.

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/04/28/workflow-receive-activity-and-message-correlation.aspx